# Theorem 2.17 Rudin's Real and complex analysis - Definition of $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, definition

In the following statement there's the usage of $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$

> Suppose $X$ is a locally compact, $\sigma$-compact Hausdorff space. If $\cal{M}$ and $\mu$ are as described in the statement of theorem 2.14, the $\cal{M}$ and $\mu$ have the following properties:
>
> 1. If $E \in \cal{M}$, there's a closed set $F$ and an open set $V$ such that $F \subset E \subset V$ and $\mu(V - F) < \epsilon$
> 2. $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$
> 3. If $E \in \cal{M}$, there're sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is an $F_{\sigma}$, $B$ is a $G_{\delta}$, $A \subset E \subset B$, and $\mu(B - A) = 0$.

I cannot find in the previous sections any definition of $F_{\sigma}$ and $G_{\delta}$. Can anyone tell me the used definitons? or where to find them.

Comment: The terms are even listed in the index of the book.  (In my copy it is in “1.11 Borel sets” on page 13.)

Comment: Is it in section 1.11 Borel Sets? $F_\sigma$ are countable unions of closed sets (which are Borel sets) while $G_\delta$ are countable union of open sets? So they're special borel sets generated by countable union and intersections. Is this the definition?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fσ_set (countable union of closed sets), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gδ_set (countable intersection of open sets).

Comment: It does, yes. I guess my question is a duplicate.